# Dynamic Rows and Columns using Angular material data table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Using basic table, I could able to render dynamic rows and column

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
      <td *ngFor="let val of row">
        {{ val }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So the same logic, when i tried it with angular mat-table I'm getting this error

`ERROR Error: Duplicate column definition name provided: "undefined"`

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="data">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let row of data">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ row }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col] }} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="data"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: data"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Please help.

**UPDATE**

I wanted to display the excel data in `mat-table`.

I can display it using simple table.

Please look into the below stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-read-table

Comment: `[matColumnDef]="col"` but how does `col` change? Therefore it's duplicate. Also. `columns: data` is another thing that looks wrong to me. It should be a string array of all the column names. See https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 1):

The following template should work.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let columnName of columnNames" [matColumnDef]="columnName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ columnName }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row[columnName] }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnNames"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnNames"></tr>
</table>
```

This expects that the array `columnNames` is defined in your component class. It should contain the property names of your row objects to be included in your table.

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-dynamic-rows-and-columns?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.html)

Comment: I tried its not working, This my stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-read-table, Upload any excel data with heading,  it should display it in `mat-table`

Comment: @aw3123: My anwer gives a viable solution to your original question. Please mark it as accepted and post a new question for this new issue.